# Copiar DataFrame a otro DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

Quiero copiar los datos de un DataFrame a otro DataFrame, pero solo quiero copiar los datos y no los nombres de las columnas o encabezados.
Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({"MES": ["ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO"],
                        "AÑO":      [2011,    2012,       2022,    2023,    2022,   2020,   2019,     2018]})
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NOM MES': [''],
                        'NUM AÑO': ['']})
    
# De esta forma me este remplazando todo el dataFrame df por df1
df1 = df.copy()
    print(df)
```

El resultado que me da es el siguiente

```
       MES   AÑO
0    ENERO  2011
1  FEBRERO  2012
2    MARZO  2022
3    ABRIL  2023
4     MAYO  2022
5    JUNIO  2020
6    JULIO  2019
7   AGOSTO  2018

import pandas as pd
        
        df = pd.DataFrame({"MES": ["ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO"],
                            "AÑO":      [2011,    2012,       2022,    2023,    2022,   2020,   2019,     2018]})
        
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NOM MES': [''],
                            'NUM AÑO': ['']})
        
    # De esta forma solo imprime los encabezados
    pd.concat([df1, df],ignore_index=True)
        print(df1)
```

El resultado que me da es el siguiente

```
NOM MES NUM AÑO
0
```

El resultado que quiero obtener, teniendo en cuenta que quiero copiar esos datos y no los encabezados de DataFrame(df) a DataFrame(df1)

```
NOM MES   NUM AÑO
0    ENERO  2011
1  FEBRERO  2012
2    MARZO  2022
3    ABRIL  2023
4     MAYO  2022
5    JUNIO  2020
6    JULIO  2019
7   AGOSTO  2018
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado utilizar así como los errores que te impiden lograr tu objetivo

Comment: Si te traigo todo el codigo que estoy haciendo te vas a enrredar y hay si no me entenderia, Simplemente estoy automatizando un informe el cual me toca constrir haciendo merge de varios libros de Excel y tambien me toca hacer filtro y pegar esos datos en otra columna, luego de construir el informe me toca pegar toda esa informacion en una platantilla para asi ir a actulizar la tabla dinamica con todas esa informacio. Ves lo largo que es.   por eso lo quise hacer asi con este breve ejemplo el cual solo quiero copiar los datos a otro libro de excel pero que no se incluyan los encabezados

Comment: Para poder darme cuenta de que los cambios si se estan haciendo cree ese otro DataFrame con sos nombre de columnas diferentes. Solo pido esa ayuda ya que he intentando de varias forma y no he conseguido lo que quiero

Comment: Ya me habias ayudado en una consulta de filtrado. Eres muy buen@s en esto, quisiera saber si te puedo contactar por otro lado

Comment: Esta bien que no hayas incluido todo el código y que hayas intentado explicarlo al mínimo, pero cuando se necesita hacer depuración es necesario un "Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable" es decir, algo que podamos copiar y pegar y que reproduzca el problema. Por otra parte, no es muy claro que has intentado para transferir los datos a `df1`, ni el error o mal comportamiento que obtienes al intentarlo.

Comment: Cuando se copia información de un `dataframe` a otro, si haces por ejemplo `join` puedes pasar la información a determinadas columnas. La duda principal que tengo es: al parecer únicamente cambian los nombres de las columnas, si es así, por qué no únicamente cambias los nombres de las columnas al transferir la información al nuevo `dataframe`?

Comment: Ok, voy a poner las formas que he intentado hacer el copiado para que me ayudes porfa

Comment: Ya actualize la informacion de la pregunta con alguna de las forma que intente. en realidad en la plantilla original las columnas se llaman igual a como esta en el dataFrame  contruido, solo que tiene una segunda hoja con unas tablas dinamicas que se actualizan de la informacion que se construye. Si hay alguna forma de contruir todos los datos en la plantilla misma sin tener que al final copiar los datos y pegarlo aya seria lo mas optimo pero no encontre como trabajarlo asi

Comment: Si copias de un df a otro df, se copia con todo. Si quieres cambiarles el nombre de columnas lo haces luego de la copia: df1.rename(columns={"MES":"NOM MES", "AÑO":"NUM AÑO"}, inplace=true).

Comment: O como puedo Guardar esos datos sin importar los nombres de las columnas en una archivo de excel que ya existe

Comment: Ah ahora si ya entendí lo que deseas hacer, deja redacto una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Una forma en la que lo puedes lograr es utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) y configurando [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) para que utilice `openpyxl`.

Utilizando el `dataframe de tu pregunta` tengo un archivo de Excel llamado `sample.xlsx` y adentro tengo una hoja de datos llamada "Prueba" y un par de celdas que serán las columnas del `dataframe`, como puedes ver en la imagen no hay más datos en la hoja de datos.

[image: Hoja de datos antes de exportar]

El código:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"MES": ["ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO"],
                        "AÑO":      [2011,    2012,       2022,    2023,    2022,   2020,   2019,     2018]})

with pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Prueba", index=False, header=False, startrow=2, startcol=1)
```

Los argumentos `index = False` y `header = False` hacen que se exporten úicamente los datos sin los índices ni los nombres de las columnas, ambos argumentos por defecto son `True`.

Ahora una imagen con el resultado:

[image: Hoja de datos después de exportar]

Como puedes observar se agregaron los datos a la hoja de datos sin sobreescribir sus valores anteriores, ten en cuenta que el modo que se utiliza es `a` que quiere decir `append` o adjuntar los datos y el `engine` debe ser `openpyxl`.

**Advertencia:** Te recomiendo hacer pruebas primero en un archivo que no sea el que deseas modificar para que compruebes que la fila y columna donde vas a insertar el `dataframe` las has configurado correctamente ya que el archivo se guarda al terminar de adjuntar el `dataframe` y podrías perder información valiosa.

**Nota adicional:** Si el archivo de Excel que tienes ha sido creado por algún programa que no es Excel, por ejemplo generado por `python` entonces podría aparecer un error diciendo que el archivo no puede abrirse por no ser un archivo `zip` pero no siempre se genera ese error, depende de como se haya creado el archivo. Todos los archivos de Excel tienen un `header` especial y aveces parte del mismo es omitido por otros programas al crear los archivos y por eso aparece ese error.

Comment: Listo amigo eres crack. Era tal cual lo que necesitaba muchas gracias bro

Comment: Recuerda que agregar la información completa a las preguntas es muy importante para que los que no estamos familiarizados con lo que deseas hacer entendamos la meta o el objetivo del código, de esa forma las respuestas serán más adecuadas. Con la información que habías puesto al inicio se entendía que deseabas copiar los datos a otro `dataframe` con diferentes nombres de columnas, por eso habíamos propuesto que únicamente los renombraras.