# Como guardar mi DataFrame sin perder las imágenes del archivo de Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Se me presenta un error en la construcción de la automatización de un proceso el cual tengo que analizar las ventas de un día con una tabla dinámica, luego tengo que pegar esos datos en un archivo ejemplo.xlsx que contiene formas he iconos. Cuando ejecuto el código efectivamente hace el proceso que deseo en la hoja VENTAS pero me eliminar todas las formas y iconos de la hoja FORMAS en el archivo ejemplo.xlsx

Este es el error que me aparece (DrawingML support is incomplete and limited to charts and images only. Shapes and drawings will be lost).

He buscado soluciones y no he podido saber como arreglar este error.
Trate de resumir el código lo máximo posible para que me entiendan

CODIGO

```
import pandas as pd

#Ruta del archivo de ventas
informe = ('C:/Users/adatos/Desktop/AUTOMATIZACION/AUTOMATIZACION INFORME VENTAS/ejemplo.xlsx')
colombia = ('C:/Users/adatos/Desktop/AUTOMATIZACION/AUTOMATIZACION INFORME VENTAS/colombia.xlsx')

#Crando DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(informe)
df1 = pd.read_excel(colombia)

#Creacion de la tabla dinamica 
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    data=df1,
    index=['Código almacén', 'Fecha'],
    aggfunc='sum'
)

pivot = pivot.reset_index()

with pd.ExcelWriter(informe, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="VENTAS", index=False, header=False, startrow=1, startcol=0)
```

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el resultado que quiero obtener es que no borre la información de formas y iconos que esta en esa hoja FORMAS así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También quisiera saber como puedo leer y modificar el archivo plantilla para después guardarlo con otro nombre o que quede con la fecha en que se ejecuta el código

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Copiar DataFrame a otro DataFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577972/copiar-dataframe-a-otro-dataframe). Acabo de probar la misma respuesta pero con una imagen y agrega los datos sin eliminar la imagen.

Comment: Por cierto, estás agregando los datos en la hoja de datos "VENTAS 2023" pero en tu foto muestras "MENÚ", ¿En alguna otra parte del código estás agregando información a esa hoja de datos?

Comment: No, en la hoja "VENTAS 2023" es donde estoy pegando loas datos y todo sale sin problema alguno. Muestro la hoja del menú por que es donde me esta eliminando casi todo lo que hay en ella

Comment: Creo que la descripción de la pregunta esta mal, ¿Son "formas" de Excel y no imágenes? Ya lo pude reproducir. En la [documentación](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) se menciona que las formas, imágenes y gráficas no se pueden conservar al escribir en un archivo que ha sido abierto y guardado con el mismo nombre, intenta guardarlo con un nombre diferente. Por cierto aunque se menciona que las imágenes no se soportan al hacer pruebas y leer en [so] en inglés se menciona que las imágenes ya se soportan.

Comment: Modifique la pregunta resumiendo lo máximo posible. Ojala me puedas ayudar con este error. Gracias