# Como puedo dejar los encabezados en una extracción de datos a excel a través de python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Necesito orientación, construí un código para automatizar la extracción de información de un data frame, esa información se extrae a un excel y los datos anteriores que se encuentren en ese excel se borran, colocandose los nuevos datos pero el problema que tengo es que se borran los encabezados también, solo necesito que se borren los datos desde las celdas A2 y se coloquen los datos también desde la celda A2 sin quitar los encabezados. Me pueden ayudar con eso porfavor?
Esta parte es la que abre el excel,borra y pega los datos.

```
# Abrir el archivo Cancelaciones_Directo.xlsx
 cancelaciones_directo = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:/Users/'+ usuario +'/OneDrive - 
 /Escritorio/Cancelaciones_fsc/Cancelaciones_Directo.xlsx')

# Verificar si la hoja Cancelación existe
  if 'Cancelación' in cancelaciones_directo.sheetnames:
# Obtener la hoja "Cancelación"
  hoja_cancelacion = cancelaciones_directo['Cancelación']
# Borrar los datos existentes en la hoja
  hoja_cancelacion.delete_rows(2, hoja_cancelacion.max_row)

  else:
# Si aplica, crea nueva hoja Cancelación
  hoja_cancelacion = cancelaciones_directo.create_sheet('Cancelación')

#Exportar los nuevos datos de cancelaciones exitosas en la hoja
  for i, fila in datos_aux.iterrows():
  hoja_cancelacion.append(fila.tolist())

# Guardar los cambios en el archivo Cancelaciones_Directo.xlsx
  cancelaciones_directo.save(r'C:/Users/'+ usuario +'/OneDrive - 
 /Escritorio/Cancelaciones_fsc/Cancelaciones_Directo.xlsx')
 cancelaciones_directo.close()
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Copiar DataFrame a otro DataFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577972/copiar-dataframe-a-otro-dataframe). Recuerda que antes de publicar una nueva pregunta es importante buscar si ya existen respuestas al mismo problema.